# Why does the system floor-round the time before review queues reset?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've noticed this before, but I'm curious, so I'll ask a question.

Close vote, flag, comment vote, vote, etc counts and review queues reset at UTC 0:00. If someone runs out of any of these before the reset, a message will pop up telling the user how much time until the reset.

The thing I've noticed is that this time left estimate seems to floor-round: for example, if there are 2:55 hours left, messages will say 2:00 hours left. It seems a little inaccurate to floor-round like that, since it can show 59 minutes less than it should.

I took this screenshot at 4:05PM Eastern (7:00PM is the reset here):

[image]

Is there a reason for this? Should it be changed?

Comment: Everytime you see a "xxx ago" or "in xxx hours" on this site, the number is always floor-rounded. This post is over 8 minutes old but it still shows as "8 minutes ago".

Comment: @NathanOsman - But he's asking *why* is it that way.

Comment: Ayyy, does it really bother you that much?

Comment: @edwinksl yes, I am absolutely obsessed....

Comment: @edwinksl (no, obviously not. I just want to know, and it'd be nice if it's mutable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would you think it a problem if this were rounded up (2:01 hours => 3 hours, for example)? If you wouldn't, someone would.

We had to pick something (given limited screen real-estate), so that's what we picked.

Comment: So it's not possible to do a rounding system that would round down below x.5 and up otherwise?

Comment: @Zacharee1 - anything is possible. And some people will disagree with whatever we choose.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Ah, the "Kobayashi Maru", 'no win' rule of UI design strikes again.  :)